# Play videos in Recyclerview android

Tags: android, video

I am working on android application and have a feature to upload videos of youtube, vimeo to server. Now I have a recyclerview to show the latest news feed in the app. I want to show these videos in the recyclerview and the videos should be played when clicked.

Now I have below requirements :

1. The played video should be stopped when the recyclerview will be scrolled down from that video.
2. When I again scroll back to that video, it should start that video from the point where it was stopped.

I am beginner in this work and do not know how to implement it. Can someone please help me so that I can implement this feature in my application.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: I think that the pause when scroll would be easy. Do you need videos from the video providers that you mentioned or can just be one of them?

Comment: Yes, videos may be from any sources from youtube and vimeo. I need to load both type of videos.

Comment: If it was only Youtube, you could use [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

Comment: No, I need to use both type of videos and want a common thing to play both type of videos. 
Thanks a lot for all your help in advanced.

Comment: Maybe [Vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/) let you upload too. If so, you can try to use both API

Comment: Try using this library https://github.com/eneim/Toro.... it is like that of in fb or tumblr app